# Problem: Stuck in GRUB

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

My problem is, that every time I boot, the computer immediately takes me to a screen that says the following:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
device or file completions.
```

This happened once before, but I had recovery media that time, and I do not have any now. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the checkmark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! For some reason, my computer overwrote bootmgfw.efi, and rewriting it is quite simple.

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: Where does that file need to be placed?